# Real-time wmv video encoding in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video, encoding

How to encode video on the fly and send it trough the network from C#?

Can't find a suitable library. I need to encode in WMV and don't mind if the actual encoding is made in C++ as long as the library has a .NET assembly available.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware of [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/), but it is native C code only.  If you're ok with interoperability this may be your ticket.

Edit: It turns out someone already wrapped this in a .NET assembly.  It's called [FFlib.NET](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/).

Answer (score 2):

I use the Windows Media Format SDK, although I admit I use it directly in C++ native code. I believe it can be called from managed code.

This is now included as part of the Windows SDK here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb190307.aspx

(or you can download it separately - see the list in the left-hand panel)

Be warned, it is a fair bit to get your head around. However, there are sample code resources which should assist.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are encoding (size, framerate, hardware, etc) real-time encoding may not even be possible.  Video encoding is VERY CPU intensive.